# Windows 10 not recognizing hard disk after reconnection

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

For some testing purposes, I opened my laptop and removed my HDD (which is a data store, my Windows is on my SSD). After reconnecting, computer itself recognizes the hard disk. From my bootloader menu, I can even boot into a Lubuntu which is installed inside a partition inside the hard disk. The data is all intact. However, after this reconnection, The Windows 10 in my SSD (which is my main OS) does not recognize the hard disk and shows Unallocated, Not Initialized in Disk Management.

I don't want to initialize and format the hard disk while I can literally access all the data inside the disk from another OS in my computer. This seems like just a Windows 10 issue. I don't know what changed after removing and reinserting the hard disk.

The hard disk is NTFS (except the partition which holds Lubuntu), and was readable from my Windows just an hour ago. It is still readable by other OS'es in my computer. Just Windows is freaking out and claims it to be unallocated and unitinialized. What could be the issue here ? I don't want to switch operating systems everytime I want to access some data in my hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the disk again
- Start Windows
- Shut down Windows
- Insert disk again
- Start Windows

And it is back to normal. I am a computer engineer, and have no clue why this happened. Perhaps someone will enlighten me after seeing this question.

Have a nice day/night.

Comment: Linux does not always handle NTFS *exactly* as Microsoft desires, and might leave the HDD "dirty" on shutdown. Did you *write* to he disk while in Lubuntu?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No nothing. Actually I first booted into Windows, saw that it was not recognized, then tried linux. Other than that, I have dual boot on my system, I use both of them regularly without any problems. This only happened with re-insertion of the disk.